# Where is Windows 10 "credentials" stored?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reinstall, windows-activation

I have a laptop that came with Windows 7 originally. It was then (1) upgraded to Windows 10 during the period in which Windows 10 was free and (2) and clean-installed with Ubuntu. As such my system at the moment only has Ubuntu installed.

During (1), there was no step to enter the Windows 10 CD key and between (1) and (2), I created a Macrium Reflect backup of my Windows partition. That backup is now misplaced.

I'm contemplating reinstalling Windows 10 on this laptop using an unmodified ISO. Will I be prompted for a CD key this time? Is there a chance that the Win 10 copy in (1) stored a copy of its credentials somewhere so that the system will remember those when I reinstall Windows?

Comment: It's not stored anywhere on your PC based on what you describe you have a digital entitlement to Windows 10.  When prompted for a key just skip that step Windows 10 will automatically activate.  If it doesn't a quick phone call to the Microsoft activation center will be required

Comment: @Ramhound How does the Windows recognize that my system previously has had Windows installed as opposed to a system that is installing Windows 10 for the first time?

Comment: @Ramhound Please note that the system is now installed with just Ubuntu.

Comment: Based on your hardware.  Tons of questions on this subject with better answers than the duplicate but the duplicate has a correct answer

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 can store a license in the UEFI bios.

Comment: @yurnero So?  You activated Windows 10 on the machine before hence the reason you have a digital entitlement now

Comment: @LPChip His hardware CANNOT the license in the ACPI table.  Their PC came with Windows 7 NO hardware that came with Window 7 has the capability to store the key in the ACPI table.  The license to Windows 8+ machines ARE NOT store in UEFI.  ACPI table isn't UEFI.  There is a difference, I am not complaining about nothing, UEFI and ACPI are two separate standards.

Comment: @Ramhound I think we might have a misunderstanding. You mention this "digital entitlement" That is what I am interested in as well although I don't know it is called that. So my question is, where is that "digital entitlement" stored?

Comment: @yurnero Microsoft's servers.  It's not stored on your PC.  Just install Windows 10 and when prompted for a key skip that step.  I promise your installation will automatically activate

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-quietly-rewrites-its-activation-rules-for-windows-10/

Comment: @Ramhound If you'll turn your last comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @yurnero it already exits. I don't duplicate answers.

Comment: @Ramhound All the same, thank you to you and LPChip.

Comment: What digital entitlement is: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-generic-key-what-is-digital-entitlement/73d3d28b-5064-4410-a9e0-63ecfe0a4f62 and http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks again Ram. That was cool of you.

Comment: And a good reference that helps explain Windows 10 activation with a digital entitlement:  http://superuser.com/q/1148506/650163

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop came with a Windows 7 CoA sticker, you **may** need to enter the key printed on that for proper activation.

If the key is embedded in your BIOS, which AFAIK is the case for UEFI machines, then you can use "Skip this step" for entering the key, and Windows should activate automatically on connecting to the internet.

Comment: SLIC worked fine with legacy BIOS. SLP (w/ SLIC) requires a certificate embedded in the install image (thus making it an "OEM image"), which is not present in retail versions and therefore will not work. At least, that was true for Win7 and maybe Win8, and probably for proper OEM Win10. But upgraded Win10 uses digital entitlements instead.