# How to do a clean install of windows 10 using cmd?

Tags: windows-10, filesystem-corruption

My HD is starting to get corrupted, and some system files are gone. But Windows still works.

The problem is that now the usual method to reset Windows is not possible for me.

My taskbar, start menu, explorer and the new windows configurations menu are gone. So far I can start the task manager and from there I can access the execute function to open cmd and the old control panel.

I just bought an SSD to replace my broken HD but I want to do a clean install without losing my Windows license.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have a `Digital License`, simply replacing your hard drive won't be a problem.  Take a few minutes to read through this previous question:  [Reset Windows 10 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1148506/reset-windows-10-from-usb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make an assumption here.  That assumption is that you have a free upgrade license.  If this is not the case please comment and I can update the answer accordingly.

Since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update your free license is associated with you Microsoft account.  This is assuming you have linked your computer with you MS account.  If you have you will simply just need to reinstall and Head to Settings > Update & Security > Activation and you’ll see a “Troubleshoot” option if activation failed. Click that option and sign in with the Microsoft account you associated your license with. You’ll be able to tell Windows that you “changed hardware on this device recently” and select your PC from a list of devices associated with your Microsoft account.

I have personally used this process and it does work.

Please note that I referenced and used some information from this [article on howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%E2%80%99s-hardware/)

If you have not associated your PC with you MS account then hopefully you system is okay enough to run start ms-settings from the command prompt and open the setting window (omit start if you are using the run dialog).

Happy installation.

Comment: Thank you! The installation was successful and there were no problems with the license.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Brutal.  This answer that worked got down voted..  @Lucas would you be kind enough to accept this answer since it worked for you?

Comment: I upvoted the answer, not sure who downvoted it. The question got a downvote though.